# Can't build Node container with volume with package.json file to run npm install

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

How does Docker build containers? I can't figure it out. I want:

- build a container
- pass local folder in it
- install npm in the container (using dockerfile) in the volume folder( so, I can see it on my local drive)
- run a command in my yaml config file

I've tried to list content of folders with `ls` command, but the `/src/` is always empty (prints: `src`)
My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  node:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.node
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
    command: run develop
    tty: true
```

My Dockerfile.node:

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./src/package*.json ./src/
RUN ls
RUN cd ./src
RUN ls
RUN npm install
RUN ls
```

On the RUN npm install command I got this error:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/src/package.json'
```

I start project with command `docker-compose up --build`

My folder structure is:

```
/
src
  --package.json
docker-compose.yml
Dockerfile.node
```

Please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: Docker doesn't really work in the way you describe.  If you want to run local commands on your local source tree, just directly run `node`; it will have many fewer pitfalls and moving parts and it will work just as well.  In general the steps in the `Dockerfile` run on an isolated copy of your source tree and will never be reflected back on the host, and everything in the `Dockerfile` happens before anything in a `docker run` command or most of the options in a `docker-compose.yml` file take effect -- in particular the build sequence never sees a mounted volume.

Comment: David Maze - thanks, good point! I've suffered a lot before knowing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cd ./src` only available in the current `RUN` command, as Dockerfile each command run in a separate shell, so when it comes to run `npm install` at this time your working is WORKDIR that is `/src`  not the one you are expecting using `cd .src` which should be `/src/src`.

```
RUN pwd
#/src
RUN cd ./src #here /src/src
RUN ls
#/src <-- back to WORKDIR, while you are expecting /src/src
RUN npm install
```

In short, there is `WORKDIR` in dockerfile not `cd`.

You have to option, change command

```
RUN cd ./src && npm i
```

or change the copy command and leave the rest as it is.

```
COPY ./src/package*.json .
```

Comment: That's the syntax I needed: cd ./src && npm i. Great thanks!